# How can I check that a big MySql dump import is working fine? Is it normal that takes a lot of time?

Tags: mysql, data-import

I am not so into database and I have the following doubt:

I have a VPS server (based on Ubuntu) on which I installed MySql. Today I am importing a datbase from a .sql dump file, I have done this operation using this statment:

```
mysql -u root -p my_db_name < db_dump.sql
```

The **db_dump.sql** is pretty big (70 mb) and it is tacking a lot of time (are more than 10 minutes that it is working).

Can this time be normal with a file having this dimension? Or can happen some problem?

How can I monitor that the import process is working? I have opened another SSH connection to my VPS and I launched the **top** statment but I am not finding something related to MySql. Why? How can I check if it is working?

**EDIT-1:** The record are a lot, it contains the definition to 5 table, the main table contains something like 110000 records related to one to many relationship with other tables. The total amount of record in all tables is something like **800000** records.

**EDIT-2:** This is the output of the **show processlist;** statment in MySql prompt

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id    | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| 15077 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
+-------+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What exactly means?

Comment: The size in MB is not as relevant as the number of rows and the number of columns in each row, and the number of indexed columns. I've seen imports of small files like yours take anywhere from 30 seconds to 20 minutes, and large files (2gb) import as quickly as 2 minutes on the right hardware.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have add something more information at the end of my original post. The record are a lot

Comment: MySQL is going to provide an error message if sg goes wrong. Be a bit patient. But you can check MySQL's error log, if you are worried. Btw 70 mb is not too big for an sql dump. To check if it is working, connect to MySQL from another command line or GUI and issue a `show processlist` statement.

Comment: Since you have multiple tables, you could split the file and import one table at a time.

Comment: @Shadow I have added a new information related the result obtained from the show processlist statment in my original post.

Comment: The import process has completed. Btw if you googled MySQL show processlist, then you would find the detailed MySQL documentation describing the output of the show processlist statement. A bit of independence would be welcomed.

Comment: @Shadow but it have imported nothing !!! and the import processi is not completed (it seems running)

Comment: If the import process were running, it would show up in the process list.

Comment: Your show procesist command shows that you are showing your processlist and nothing more. Normally import will show some dml statements in the processlist.